# CUDA driver API: Where is nvcuda?

Tags: cuda

The CUDA C Programming Guide Version 4.2 states:

```
The driver API is implemented in the nvcuda dynamic library which is copied on 
the system during the installation of the device driver.
```

I installed the RC5.0 devdriver on my Linux box along with SDK 4.2 and 5.0. Right now I have difficulties finding this library. Its not in (or under) `/usr`, `/lib`, `/lib64`, nor in one of the SDK libs:

CUDA 4.2:

```
ls /usr/local/cuda-4.2/cuda/lib64/

libcublas.so        libcudart.so        libcufft.so        libcuinj.so        libcurand.so        libcusparse.so        libnpp.so
libcublas.so.4      libcudart.so.4      libcufft.so.4      libcuinj.so.4      libcurand.so.4      libcusparse.so.4      libnpp.so.4
libcublas.so.4.2.9  libcudart.so.4.2.9  libcufft.so.4.2.9  libcuinj.so.4.2.9  libcurand.so.4.2.9  libcusparse.so.4.2.9  libnpp.so.4.2.9
```

CUDA 5.0:

```
ls /usr/local/cuda-5.0/cuda/lib64/

libcublas.so        libcudart.so        libcufft.so        libcuinj.so        libcurand.so        libcusparse.so        libnpp.so        libnvToolsExt.so
libcublas.so.5.0    libcudart.so.5.0    libcufft.so.5.0    libcuinj.so.5.0    libcurand.so.5.0    libcusparse.so.5.0    libnpp.so.5.0    libnvToolsExt.so.5.0
libcublas.so.5.0.7  libcudart.so.5.0.7  libcufft.so.5.0.7  libcuinj.so.5.0.7  libcurand.so.5.0.7  libcusparse.so.5.0.7  libnpp.so.5.0.7  libnvToolsExt.so.5.0.7
```

Where is this library installed to?

It's not that the driver API is not included in the RC 5.0. I just reinstalled devdriver 4.2 and its still not in the above mentioned places.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. As both answers point out, this is a typo (throwback to earlier days). I have filed a bug against the CUDA documentation to get this fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. But under a different name (`libcuda` instead `libnvcuda`):

```
/usr/lib/libcuda.so.295.41
```

This must be a typo/error in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

`libcuda` is always **by default** installed to `/usr/lib/` and on 64bit linux `/usr/lib64`

See also [Chapter 5. Listing of Installed Components](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/280.13/README/installedcomponents.html) for list and locations of other driver components.